# emacs vimpulse errors

Tags: emacs, vimpulse

I've just recently started to use emacs a bit, solely for [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/). I'm a heavy vim user, so I installed [vimpulse](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse.el) to attempt to keep my org-mode usage as close to vim as possible.

However, I've been hitting some errors when I try to use some features. For example, if I press `V` for visual line mode, select some lines, and then push `d`, it should delete those lines. Instead, I get the following error:

`Symbol's function definition is void: vimpulse-delete-text-objects-function`

Similarly, if I try to use `ciw` for "change this word", I get (after hitting the `i`):

`Symbol's function definition is void: vimpulse-change-text-objects-command`

If I open the source for vimpulse, I can clearly see the definitions for these two functions, so they're not undefined. That was about my best guess though as to what could be causing this. Anyone with more experience with emacs/vimpulse that knows what's actually going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running emacs without any of your customizations:

```
emacs -q
```

Then manually load in the `vimpulse` and `org-mode` packages:

```
M-x find-file /path/to/some/org-file
M-x org-mode
M-x load-file /path/to/vimpulse.el RET
```

And try your <kbd>cid</kbd> and <kbd>v DOWN DOWN d</kbd>.

I expect that will work properly (it did for me, Emacs 23.1).  If it does, then you've got something in your `.emacs` that's mussing stuff up.  If not, then we've got to do some more debugging.

Comment: Following those steps, nothing works at all. Even pushing h/j/k/l to move around the file does not work, it just inserts the characters. Perhaps it's related to me running emacs on windows?